# Can Adobe Bridge metadata be transferred to iTunes?

Tags: itunes, metadata, adobe-bridge

I'm thinking of using Adobe Bridge as my digital media manager (ebooks, audio, video, etc), as it's really powerful when it comes to managing and organizing stuff, and it has some cool features that I like which don't exist (currently) in iTunes.

If (someday) I wanted to move to iTunes, will I be able to get all my metadata (Artist, Genre, Album, Release data, Description, keywords) that I've already assigned to my files?

Comment: As long as Adobe Bridge uses ID3 to store it's metadata there shouldn't be a problem, as Apple devices use it for artwork, which is embedded in the .mp3 or AAC music file.